# How to customize QCompleter Completion Rules with QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: pyqt, qcombobox, qcompleter, qsortfilterproxymodel

eg i have these three items in my QComboBox dropdown list

```
chicken soup
chilli peppers
grilled chicken
```

entering "ch" would match "chicken soup" and "chilli peppers" but not "grilled chicken".

What I want is to be able to enter "ch" and match all of them or, more specifically, "chicken" and match "chicken soup" and "grilled chicken".

reference:
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-7830

the following code works only one time, why ? 
if you enter 'a', all string contain 'a' show up correctly, you got 3 results returned , 'Jane Doe','Albert Einstein', 'Alfred E Newman'
but if you continue to enter 'n', no result show in the drop down menu.

edit: it works but the popup QListView is not displayed properly ( if you press down arrow key, the matched items will show in the combobox editing area, but the drop down list is not shown )

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

import sys

import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)


class MyGui(QDialog): 

    def __init__(self, parent=None): 

        super(MyGui,self).__init__(parent)

        model = QtGui.QStringListModel()
        wordList = ['John Doe','Jane Doe','Albert Einstein', 'Alfred E Newman']
        model.setStringList(wordList)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.line = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.line)

        self.combobox = QComboBox(parent)
        layout.addWidget(self.combobox)
        self.combobox.addItems(wordList)
        self.combobox.setEditable(True)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        complete = CustomQCompleter2(self)
        complete.setModel(model)
        complete.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        complete.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        complete.setWrapAround(False)

        self.line.setCompleter(complete)
        self.combobox.setCompleter(complete)
        self.combobox.setEditText('')

        self.setGeometry(200, 100, 400, 300)


class CustomQCompleter2(QCompleter):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomQCompleter2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.local_completion_prefix = ""
        self.source_model = None

    def setModel(self, model):
        self.source_model = model
        super(CustomQCompleter2, self).setModel(self.source_model)

    def updateModel(self):
        local_completion_prefix = self.local_completion_prefix
        class InnerProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
            def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
                index0 = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent)
                searchStr = local_completion_prefix.lower()
                modelStr = self.sourceModel().data(index0,Qt.DisplayRole).toString().toLower()
                print searchStr,' in ',modelStr, searchStr in modelStr
                return searchStr in modelStr


        proxy_model = InnerProxyModel()

        proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.source_model)

        super(CustomQCompleter2, self).setModel(proxy_model)
        print 'match :',proxy_model.rowCount()


    def splitPath(self, path):
        self.local_completion_prefix = str(path)
        self.updateModel()
        return ""

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MyGui()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That code is working fine for me. Entering `an` opens up popup with 3 choices.

Answer (score 1):

adding the following code to the end of    `updateModel`  method of the completer solves the problem,but i don't know why it works.

```
cr=QRect(QPoint(1, 1), QSize(1, 1))
self.complete(cr)
```